What are the matrix entries of a linear tranformation in terms of the inner product with non-orthnormal bases?
For a linear transformation $T: V \to W$, where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces with dimensions $n$ and $m$ and bases $\mathcal{V} = \lbrace v_1 \dots v_n\rbrace$ and $\mathcal{W} = \lbrace w_1 \dots w_m \rbrace$, respectively, the associated matrix $A_{\mathcal{W}}^{\mathcal{V}}$ has entries $a_{ij}$.  I sometimes come across that $a_{ij} = \langle w_j, T(v_i) \rangle$. But is this true in general or just for orthonormal bases? In an orthonormal basis, this inner product (assume the standard dot product) corresponds to the projection of $T(v_i)$ along $w_j$, and gives the $a_{ij}$ matrix entry, but I think this is not true for non-orthnormal bases. What is the right expression in the non-orthonromal case?
Edit: I think it actually is applicable to all bases because the expression does give the component along $w_j$ in any target basis.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle w_j, T(v_i) \rangle &= \langle w_j, \alpha_1w_1 + \dots + \alpha_j w_j + \dots + \alpha w_m \rangle
\\ &= \langle w_j, \alpha_1 w_1 \rangle + \dots + \langle w_j, \alpha_j w_j \rangle + \dots + \langle w_j, \alpha_m w_m \rangle
\\ &= w^*_j(\alpha_1 w_1) + \dots + w^*_j(\alpha_j w_j) + \dots + w_j^*(\alpha_mw_m)
\\ &= 0 + \dots + \alpha_j + \dots + 0.
\end{aligned}
$$
$w_j^*$ is the dual basis, whose property is that $w_j^*(w_i) = \delta_{ij}$.

I don't think your edit is correct.
Consider your vector space $W$ doesn't possess the Euclidean metric, that is, the matrix $g_{kl} = \langle w_k, w_l\rangle$ is not unity (which is basically the property of any non-orthonormal basis). In this case your expansion takes the form:
$$
\langle w_k, T(v_i)\rangle = 
\langle w_k, \sum_{l=1}^{m}\alpha^{l}w_{l}\rangle =
\sum_{l=1}^{m}\alpha^{l} \langle w_k, w_{l}\rangle = 
\sum_{l=1}^{m}\alpha^{l} g_{kl}
$$

Yes, you're right.

Let $G$ be a Gram matrix for the metric. Its entries are $g_{ij} = \langle w_i, w_j \rangle$, and its inverse is $G^{-1}$ with entries $g^{-1}{ij}$.  Then,
$$ a{ij} = g^{-1}_{ik}\langle w_k, T(v_i) \rangle$$
